# Windows App Cert Kit Debug App Check error

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, wack

When I run the windows app certification kit on my metro app, it passes everything except the Debug App Check. It gives the following error:

```
Failed to extract imported API information for this application
```

Is anyone else getting this error? I've tried rebuilding, uninstalling and re-deploying just the release version, doing that without hitting run, all doesn't make the error go away.

Note: I am using the Rx Extensions beta library in the application, which uses the portable library project. That's my best guess so far as to what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest pre-build 2.0.20612-rc of RX (non-portable) is accepted by App Cert Kit just fine!

However BCL Team has noted about cert error on Portable libraries:
"This is a bug in the RC version of the tools, and will be fixed to enable full support for Portable Class Libraries for Windows 8 RTM."
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/06/18/portable-libraries-and-the-windows-app-certification-kit-rc.aspx

The funny thing is that some portable libraries in our solution do pass certification.
Looks like it depends on set of classes used in the library.

We had to move code from failed portable class libraries to Metro class libraries to pass Cert Kit check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got this error with Rx.  <s>It's my understanding that that current build of Rx will not pass WACK.</s> (Edit: [The RC version of Rx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/20/reactive-extensions-v2-0-release-candidate-available-now.aspx) appears to support Metro style apps)

In general, once the WACK has finished running, you can find detailed debug information about the failures in …

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit

I believe they get overwritten with each run, so be careful there. In your case, the file post_process_trace_DebugAppCheck_*.txt will give you detailed information about why the WACK thinks your Assemblies are in debug version.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the issue is with portable class libraries. WACK cannot load System.Core version 2.0.5.0 which is referenced in most portable libraries.

Solution is to use Metro class library, until WACK is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I also get a FAIL as soon as I reference a Portable Libary